# How to create title in a box of TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a [TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) as below:

[image: TextField]

I'm using this code:

```
       TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            labelText: "Last Name",
            fillColor: Colors.transparent,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(),
            ),
          ),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "Poppins",
          ),
        ),
```

But It did not match with my expectations:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `OutlineInputBorder` into `UnderlineInputBorder` like this :

```
        border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
```

It will look like this :

[image]

Or if you don't want any UnderlineBorder you can use `InputBorder.none`

```
border: InputBorder.none,
```

It look like this :

[image]

Comment: But I want to have a box with a border. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Wrap your TextField with Card will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use a Card Widget , it will look quite similar to what you would like to accomplish , [![enter image description here][1]][1]

it will look something like this .
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edzcu.png

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Center(
  child: Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        const ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.album),
          title: Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
          subtitle: Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
        ),
        ButtonBar(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: const Text('BUY TICKETS'),
              onPressed: () {/* ... */},
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: const Text('LISTEN'),
              onPressed: () {/* ... */},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}